# Transparent background is not working correctly in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, lightbox

Basically it is a lightbox demo. The code is from [here.](http://www.cssjockey.com/web-design-tutorials/an-easy-way-to-create-light-box-with-jquery-css/comment-page-4#comments) I want to click a link "Show Panel" then pop out a form.
It works well in Firefox but wrong in IE9.

The html code is quite simple:

```
<body>
<a id="show-panel" href="#">Show Panel</a>

 <div id="lightbox-panel">
    <h2>Lightbox Panel</h2>
    <p>You can add any valid content here.</p>
    <p align="center">
    <a id="close-panel" href="#">Close this window</a>
    </p>
    </div><!-- /lightbox-panel -->

    <div id="lightbox"> </div><!-- /lightbox -->
    </body>
```

The CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

#lightbox {
display:none;
opacity:0.9;
filter:alpha(opacity=90);
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
min-width:100%;
min-height:100%;
z-index:1000;
background-color: #FFCC66;
    }

#lightbox-panel {
display:none;
position:fixed;
top:180px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-200px;
width:450px;
border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
z-index:1001;
background-color: #999900;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 15px;
    }

.show-panel {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: xx-large;
    }
    </style>
```

The JQuery code:

```
$("a#show-panel").click(function(){
$("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);
})
 $("a#close-panel").click(function(){
 $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
 })
```

The effect in firefox:
[image: firebox]

The effect in IE9:
[image: IE9]

You see not only the Transparent background but also the position of the lightbox are not right.

Thanks for help.

The entire code:

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=03a8bb9eaeeff1db#cid=03A8BB9EAEEFF1DB&id=3A8BB9EAEEFF1DB!234

Comment: Just face it: IE sucks like an Electrolux.

Comment: IE blows like a vacuum (get it? because that is not what it is supposed to do!)

Comment: I smell the doctype thingy :) @Love Have you used proper doctype ?

Comment: @Jashwant - Yep. Near certain. Why don't you write it as an answer?

Comment: You could try to set all these things using jQuery (.css method), and then look at the generated css (aka. style on an element). Then just copy that. jQuery is supposed to ensure cross platform support.

Comment: Has anyone tried IE10? I've been using it for a while now and it's really rather good.

Comment: Non-adoption of standards by IE has caused the loss of millions of man hours in development and set development of the web back years. Don't encourage Microsoft by using their browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Issue

As Jashwant said it might be a doctype issue. And thats exactly the issue. It was fixed once I put added the HTML 5 doctype in front of the `<html>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Remember that IE isn't as smart as some other browsers. So you should use the correct setup for a webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

It does seem to be working on this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJ6Sa/1/).

I do see you said it works fine on the JsFiddle on your side too. So, could you post your whole HTML on a `pasteTool` like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)? That would make fixing this easier.

One thing, I want to point out though is that the way your centering the lightbox vertically is not even.

The width of the lightbox is `450px` so for the `margin-left` you are going to want to half that. Half of 450 is 225, so your new `margin-left` is -225px.

This would make it perfectly in the center. I also like using JavaScript to get the width of the object and do the math in there. Which will take the page a little longer to load since it has to do a little more work but I think it works pretty well.

This is a little off topic considering that to you the lightbox doesn't seem to be working on that HTML page but I thought this might also be useful. Make sure you check your HTML again. There might be an issue that IE can't fix while other browsers like Google Chrome can.

Oh and if you want to center the lightbox horizontally you can use the same method, you just half the height and use the negative form of that in the `margin-top`

Comment: This would be everything you need to fix this. Please select a best answer.

Answer (score 1):

It may be `doctype` problem.

Put this before your `<html>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Also,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in `head` section.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working for me. Are you positive there isnt something else causing the issue?

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a9hnb/1/)

I would recommend setting the height and width of the html and body tags as well. I am not sure if this is the cause, but I think it will help.

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

I have create an example of just the content you have given us in a html file and it seems to work correctly. I think we need more information. These are the contents that I put in the html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #lightbox {
                display:none;
                opacity:0.9;
                filter:alpha(opacity=90);
                position:fixed;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                min-width:100%;
                min-height:100%;
                z-index:1000;
                background-color: #FFCC66;
            }

            #lightbox-panel {
                display:none;
                position:fixed;
                top:180px;
                left:50%;
                margin-left:-200px;
                width:450px;
                border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
                z-index:1001;
                background-color: #999900;
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-right: 15px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                padding-left: 15px;
            }

            .show-panel {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: xx-large;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="show-panel" href="#">Show Panel</a>

        <div id="lightbox-panel">
            <h2>Lightbox Panel</h2>

            <p>You can add any valid content here.</p>
            <p align="center">
                <a id="close-panel" href="#">Close this window</a>
            </p>
        </div><!-- /lightbox-panel -->

        <div id="lightbox"> </div><!-- /lightbox -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("a#show-panel").click(function(){
                $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);
            });

            $("a#close-panel").click(function(){
                $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I compare my test to the one you have given us you are missing the doctype. As soon as I added the doctype everything worked properly.

Comment: It does work in jsfiddle but not in real html file.Could you please verify it?

Comment: So you just tried in is jsfiddle and it worked too? Can you give us more information. Is there any other content or css on your page that could be causing issues?

Comment: No other issue to cause it, I just create a simple html file that only includes the information I provided(you can do it as well). Also there were some disscussion about transparent in the original link, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Can you please include all of the contents of your html file then?

Comment: Dont see the point in adding 100% width and height since thats what its suppose to be by default. But maybe thats an IE issue?

Comment: @Love I have pasted a demo that I created on my machine using your code. Everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: I have <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> <html> <head> <title></title> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312"> in real case.

Comment: @Love When I compare my test to the one you have given us you are missing the doctype. As soon as I added the doctype everything worked properly.

Comment: Is there any reason you do not want to give us your actual version. If you need to, you can remove any important info.